# Автокомплит Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Добавил автокомплит для поля select, значение v-model="selected" отображается, при загрузке страницы, но в дропдауне нету значений из itemList, как исправить это?

```
Select
   <v-select
      v-model="selected"
      :items="itemList"
      :search-input.sync="searchInput"
      autocomplete
   />
```

```
data: function () {
            return {
                itemList: ['one', 'two'],
                searchInput: '',
                selected: 'one'
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял вы используете пакет https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-select

если да, то у вас ошибка вместо `:items="itemList"` нужно записать `:options="itemList"`

Взято из доки https://vue-select.org/guide/options.html#options-prop

Здесь есть живой пример https://codepen.io/swartex/pen/rNNzLbq